# NVL WITH DISTINCT IN PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

why NVL function is not working with distinct in pl/sql?

Eg:

```
select DISTINCT (NVL(b.state_id,'0')) 
From branch_detail b 
where b.state_name like ('TAMILNADU%')
```

Here is the table structure(

```
branch_detail
=====================

state_id   state_name
--------   ---------
  1          kerala
  1          kerala
  2          karnataka
  2          karnataka
```

Expected Output: 0

Comment: You need to explain why NVL() isn't working the way you expect.  Please provide some test data plus desired  and actual output,  Otherwise your question will get closed and you won't get an answer.

Comment: whats more you are expecting?....Experience is the name everyone gives to their mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NVL()` function replaces a NULL in a result set.  There must be returned rows for it to work.

> "how can I handle if it returns no row"

You need to generate a row.  This might be a bit of a cheat but it does what you want to do:

```
SQL> Select distinct (nvl(b.state_id,'0')) 
  2  from ( select 'tamilnadu' as state_name from dual ) t
  3       left outer join branch_detail b 
  4      on b.state_name = t.state_name
  5  /

(NVL(B.STATE_ID,'0'))
---------------------
                    0

SQL> select distinct (nvl(b.state_id,'0')) 
  2  from ( select 'kerala' as state_name from dual ) t
  3         left outer join branch_detail b 
  4      on b.state_name = t.state_name
  5  /

(NVL(B.STATE_ID,'0'))
---------------------
                    1

SQL>
```

The inline view `t` fakes a row for the searched value; the left outer join means you'll get a row back it there isn't a match in the `branch_detail` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot..will work on this

Answer (score 0):

The NVL function will return the value 0 only if the value for state_id is null. Here in your case i think there are no rows returned from the above query. Hence the result is not displayed. I think it will work only if the value returned for the query is null.

Comment: how can I handle if it returns no row?...Thanks for your reply

Comment: I think you need to write the code to handle this issue. If 'sql%rowcount =0' then set the value whatever u need else display the value that is returned